# Linear optimisation and limitation in R

Tags: r, memory, optimization, size

We are trying to solve the next linear optimization problem:
We have:

```
Pij, i=1:3, j=1:30000, Pij are positive
Bi, i=1:3, integer positive
```

The searching result is matrix of `3 x 30000` of binary values `Xij` with next conditions:

Constraints:

```
For each j =1:30000, Sum (by index of i=1:3)Xij=1 
For each i =1:3, Sum by index of (j=1:30000) Xij≤Bi
```

Objective: Optimize:

```
Maximize (Sum (by index of i=1:3) Sum (by index of j=1:30000) Pij *Xij)
```

The decision was to reduce this task to a linear programming task. Hence we construct one matrix with `3 x 3*j` dimension for the `Bi` constraints and one matrix `j x 3*j` dimension for the `Xij` constrains. Then, the two matrixes should be combined vertically as constraint of task – the received matrix is `3+j x 3*j` dimensional. The object vector is constructed by `Pij` but as vector `3*j x 1`. The rhs constraint is combination between `Bi (1 x 3)` and vector of `1 (1 x j)` – vector is `1 x 3+j`.

It worked with lp or Rglpk_solve_LP.
I checked this with several combinations. It worked for `j=5000`, but it doesn’t worked for `j=10000`. We should use it for `30000` cases. The matrixes became too large.

Is it possible to solve this task in another way?

My computer has 8GB RAM. The size of matrix is 15.6GB. The returned error is:

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 15.6 Gb

What are the limitation for the linear programing procedure?

Are they come only by RAM of computer and size of matrixes?

Comment: This is not an LP but a MIP, and a very large one. You need probably a commercial solver for this to handle this.. Holding the constraint matrix A in memory as a dense matrix is probably not going to work, so you may need to export the data for this model, and then model things outside of R.

Comment: Is there another way to solve this task in R? Not with linear programing procedure?

Comment: You could try to develop a heuristic.May be using some meta-heuristic framework. You loose optimality then and you'll have to settle for just a good solution.

Comment: Looking at the math, this looks likes a transportation problem. This would fall in a class of network problems for which fast solvers exist.

Comment: Thank you for the answers provided.